# Listen to custom component event inside directive

Tags: angular

Is there a way to listen to the custom event `customDirective` of the `lib-test` component inside `customDirective` without them knowing anything about each other?

The current implementation only works for native events.

```html
<lib-test [customDirective]="'actionComplete'></lib-test>
```

```
@Directive({ selector: '[`customDirective`]' })
export class CustomDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() customDirective: string;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(
      this.elRef.nativeElement,
      this.customDirective || 'click',
      (event: Event) => this.trackEvent(event)
    );
  }
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent {
  @Output() actionComplete: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `actionComplete` custom event? What exactly are you trying to achieve? You want to be able to provide a function to the directive that it can call?

Comment: Hi @ShahzadB, the event name would be the name of the input of the component. In this case `actionComplete`. What I try to achieve is that the directive executes an internal function when the event is emitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation works only on native DOM events (like `click` and `mouseout`),
because `Renderer2.listen` listens just to DOM events, not to Angular's `Output()` events.

To achieve your target you should write something like this:

```
  constructor(
    private view: ViewContainerRef,
  ) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    let component = this.view["_data"].componentView.component
    (component[this.CustomEvent] as EventEmitter<any>)
        .subscribe(event => this.trackEvent(event));
    }
  }
```

If you want to write a combined directive that works on native & custom events, see [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-85qfua). It contains `NativeEventDirective`, `CustomEventDirective` & `CombinedEventDirective`.

Comment: Surprise surprise, Ivy has landed and this does not work. Any other way to achieve the same? :) Thanks